# Iphone crash on language change

Tags: objective-c

When I change international options (language) in iphone simulator, it crashes but had no errors, then if i restart everything is ok, it does this with numerous examples, is a normal thing? How can I prevent it?

Comment: What version of Xcode do you have installed?

Answer (score 0):

You can try re-installing the tools to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly normal.

When the system language changes, running applications are stopped, as there is no built-in way to change the language at runtime.
This way, it ensures applications are reloaded with the correct language.